# On some specific pages, suddenly getting "500 Internal Server Error" (SugarCRM)

Tags: sugarcrm, internal-server-error

i am using SugarCRM 6.5.x CE version. And since couple of days, I am getting a "500 internal server error" error, on clicking of "Assigned to" relate field. Actually I am using Team plugin, where after selection of team, when i try to select user, I get this error. And this is only getting on selection of some specific teams. Since one and half year, we didn't face any such error. Any idea, why it is causing this, suddenly, from out of nowhere?

[image]

We will appreciate any help. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Please perform "*Quick Repair and Rebuild*" and also perform "*Repair Roles*" and "*Repair Teams*".

If still problem persists then go for **error logs**